# Weird behaviour on Pandas df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have a Python class similar to

```
class MyClass(namedtuple('mytuple', 'one two')):
    def method1:
        pass
```

And a Pandas dataframe with 4 columns. When I try to apply the following lambda to the dataframe:

```
df.apply(lambda x: MyClass(x['col1'], x['col2']), axis=1)
```

i get the following error:

`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (218039, 2), indices imply (218039, 4)`

which is exactly the same error you get when you try to return a tuple on DataFrame.apply(), e.g.
`df.apply(lambda x: (1,2), axis=1)`

However, if I define `MyClass` as

```
class MyClass2:
    def __init__(self, one, two):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two   
    def method1():
        pass
```

the .apply() method returns successfully (a DataFrame with n rows of MyClass2 objects)

Is this the expected behaviour? It seems that df.apply() is treating the instance of a class, instantiated with a namedtuple, as a namedtuple.

EDIT: I tested the following on iPython, after the comment by @root

```
In [30]: data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,5)));

In [33]: type(data)
Out[33]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame 

In [33]: data.shape
Out[33]: (4, 5)

In [34]: data.apply(lambda x: (1,2),axis=1)
Out[34]: 
0    (1, 2)
1    (1, 2)
2    (1, 2)
3    (1, 2)
dtype: object
```

So, no problem when starting with an empty dataframe

However, with the original data the following happens

```
In [41]: type(data)
Out[41]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
In [42]: pd.__version__
Out[42]: '0.19.2'
In [43]: data.head(1)
Out[43]: 
       date_start            date_end  start_lng  start_lat
0 2015-12-03 16:25:18 2015-12-03 16:28:56  -8.680015  41.172069
In [44]: data.shape
Out[44]: (218039, 4)

In [45]: data.apply(lambda x: (1,2),axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4263, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2761, in __init__
self._verify_integrity()
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2971, in _verify_integrity
construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4233, in construction_error
passed, implied))

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (218039, 2), indices imply (218039, 4)
```

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: What version of pandas as you using?  I don't get an error from your first example, nor the simple `df.apply(lambda x: (1,2), axis=1)`, both of which return a column of tuples.  Also, your first example is class inheritance, so it essentially is a namedtuple.

Comment: I'm using Pandas 0.19.2
I edited my original post to reflect some experiments I did which left me even more confused